# How to fix, checkbox not checked using code in custom adapter for a spinner?

Tags: java, android, adapter, android-recyclerview, custom-adapter

I am setting up a custom spinner with "Text & Checkbox" using custom adapter. How can i set checked some of the checkbox that already selected by user? while clicking on the checkbox values shows correctly.

I am setting the selected check box from the model class but it is not getting checked.It is true and the model class of the object having value "True" only. Also i have checked using the "setSelected" & "setChecked" but both gives the same output.

```
public View getCustomView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflator = LayoutInflater.from(thisActivity);
            convertView = layoutInflator.inflate(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_with_checkbox, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.mTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
            holder.mCheckBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }


        holder.mTextView.setText(listState.get(position).getTitle());

        // To check weather checked event fire from getview() or user input
        isFromView = true;


        //holder.mCheckBox.setChecked(listState.get(position).isSelected());
        isFromView = false;

        Logger.infoLog("adapter vehicleMovementSubEdit= =>" + vehicleMovementSubEdit);

        Logger.infoLog("enteredLaneIdList string ==>" + selectedReasonsList.toString());


        holder.mCheckBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        holder.mCheckBox.setTag(position);


//        holder.mCheckBox.setChecked(listState.get(position).getChecked());

        Logger.infoLog("listState.get(position).getId() ==>" + listState.get(position).getId());
        Logger.infoLog("selectedReasonsList.contains(listState.get(position).getId()) ==>" + selectedReasonsList.contains(listState.get(position).getId()));

        if (selectedReasonsList.contains(listState.get(position).getId())) {

            listState.get(position).setSelected(true);

            Logger.infoLog("condition true ==>");

            if (listState.get(position).getChecked()) {
                Logger.infoLog("double condition true ==>");
                holder.mCheckBox.setChecked(listState.get(position).isSelected());

            }
        }else{
            Logger.infoLog("condition false ==>");
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If they are checked, but don't visually show it, you may need to poke them.

```
View v = getView();

if (v != null)
{
    v.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState();
}
```

Comment: yes they were checked but doesn't view visually. Thanks for the help. May I Know where we need to do the above in adapter?

Comment: Tried this but not helped